# Nuget packages are not visible after publishing to private website

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package, nuget-server

I followed the instructions on Hosting Your Own NuGet Feeds:

1. Create an empty web application Installed the NuGet.Server package.
2. Set ~/Packages as the packagesPath in Web.config Set my API key in Web.config.
3. Created the .nupkg file from a class library using NuGet.exe.
4. Copy .nupkg file in Package folder of my website where I published it.
5. When I go to my server http://nugetserver.myserver.com/nuget then I don't see any nuget package published. Whereas, if I published on local machine then I can see nuget package in visual studio.
6. Packages are published at default path i.e. ~/packages folder.

**XML of nuget Url look like:**

```
<service xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xml:base="http://nugetserver.terebrum.com/nuget/">
<workspace>
<atom:title>Default</atom:title>
<collection href="Packages">
<atom:title>Packages</atom:title>
</collection>
</workspace>
</service>
```

And Visual Studio Nuget Page is Blank:

[image]

What am I missing here? I have already given permissions to packages folder on server.